# Insert array into a call of a plugin in jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm using the plugin backstretch for my site. If I want to use this in  static mode I can do in this mode:

```
$.backstretch([
  "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/outside.jpg"
   , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg"
   , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/cheers.jpg"]
   , {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
```

But if I want to do this in dynamic mode i have thinked to pass an array to teh backstretch like this:

```
 var arr2 = "[\"img/home/1.jpg\", \"img/home/2.jpg\"]";

 $.backstretch(
    arr2, {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
```

I have also tried:

```
var arr = new Array();
 for (var i=1; i<3; i++){
    arr.push("img/home/"+i+".jpg");
 }
```

But this doesn't work.. why?

Comment: Why making arr2 a string, when you need an array ? Try `var arr2 = ["img/home/1.jpg", "img/home/2.jpg"];

 $.backstretch(
    arr2, {duration: 3000, fade: 750});`

Comment: yeah it works, Answer to the question and I accept it.. mine error great! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why making arr2 a string, when you need an array ? 
Try,

```
var arr2 = ["img/home/1.jpg", "img/home/2.jpg"]; 
$.backstretch(arr2, {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
```

**Edit:** (after comment)

You can add like this,

```
var arr2 = [];
arr2.push("img/home/1.jpg");
arr2.push("img/home/2.jpg");
```

and so on...

You can also pass more than one argument in `push()` function.

```
arr2.push("img/home/1.jpg","img/home/2.jpg");
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: but if i want to insert element into this array dynamically? Is the same thing to write this code arr2.push("img/home/1.jpg");  arr2.push("img/home/2.jpg"); and your code?